# Is there an easy way to migrate from nuxt-axios to $fetch and useAsyncData in nuxt 3?

Tags: plugins, axios, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm currently migrating a web app built with nuxt 2 (which uses axios to perform requests to the api) to nuxt 3. I just started working on it and I realized that there's no nuxt-axios for nuxt 3, instead I have to use useFetch or useAsyncData + $fecth (which I think is challenging and exciting).

But... I have a problem with maintaining the headers across the whole application. In the previous version I could just create a axios plugin, use the interceptors and add authorization tokens and other stuff to the header. I've searched and read a lot about these new composables but I failed to create a similar solution.

Here's my current (in progress) solution:

```js
import { $fetch, type FetchOptions } from 'ofetch'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ $config }) => {
  const globalFetchOptions: FetchOptions = {
    baseURL: $config.public.apiURL,
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': 'es-AR',
    },
    async onRequest(_context) {},
    async onRequestError(_context) {},
    async onResponse(_context) {},
    async onResponseError(_context) {},
  }

  const apiFetch = $fetch.create(globalFetchOptions)

  const api = {
    async get(url: string, options: FetchOptions) {
      return await apiFetch(url, { method: 'get', ...options })
    },
    async post(url: string, options: FetchOptions) {
      return await apiFetch(url, { method: 'post', ...options })
    },
    async delete(url: string, options: FetchOptions) {
      return await apiFetch(url, { method: 'delete', ...options })
    },
    async put(url: string, options: FetchOptions) {
      return await apiFetch(url, { method: 'put', ...options })
    },
    async patch(url: string, options: FetchOptions) {
      return await apiFetch(url, { method: 'patch', ...options })
    },
  }

  return {
    provide: {
      api,
    },
  }
})
```

My idea is to provide straight-forward methods to use out of the box (get, post, put, etc.) provided by the plugin called `$api`.

And why I want to do this? Two reasons:

1. This is the way I was working so far.
2. I need to make sure that the headers and auth token remain is the same for all requests across the application (as long as there's no need to change the headers).

So... Could anyone give some insight about aproaching this? any thought is apreciated.